# Pandas dataframe new column from everything after the last backslash

Tags: pandas, dataframe, backslash

I have the following dataframe.

| ID | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C:\Users\user1\Documents\fb_working\Testdata\Patterns\NLP Patterns |
| 2 | C:\Users\user1\Documents\fb_working\Testdata\Patterns\NLP Patterns |

I want to create a new column with everything after the
last backslash in the location column as shown below

| ID | Location | New_Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C:\Users\user1\Documents\fb_working\Testdata\Patterns\NLP Patterns | NLP Patterns |
| 2 | C:\Users\user1\Documents\fb_working\Testdata\Patterns\NLP Patterns | NLP Patterns |

How can I do this? I'm having trouble using backslash as a delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```
df["New_Location"] = df["Location"].str.split(pat="\\", n=7, expand=False).str[-1]
```